# Digital Ocean Kubernetes Let's Encrypt Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I have been trying to deploy a Kubernetes cluster in Digital Ocean. Everything seems to work except when I try to apply the tls certificates. I have been following these steps, but with `Nginx Ingress Controller` v1.0.0 and `cert-manager` v1.5.0.

I have two urls, let's say `api.example.com` and `www.example.com`

Checking the challenge I saw `Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request...`

I tried adding the following annotations to the ingress:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
```

Or using this service as a workaround:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-enable-proxy-protocol: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-hostname: "www.example.com"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  #CHANGE/ADD THIS
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
```

If I go to the URL challenge I am able to see the hash, but I am stuck, I am not sure why it is failing or the steps to solve this.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak thanks for the comments, I am using version `Kubernetes 1.21.2-do.2`

Comment: Did you see [this topic](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes#step-2-%E2%80%94-setting-up-the-kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller) and [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/issue-with-waiting-for-http-01-challenge-propagation-failed-to-perform-self-check-get-request-from-acme-challenges)?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak thanks for the comment. Yes, a the beginning I though that the point 5 was optional, but then I realized that it should be updating the load balancer. I think I am making an error with the annotations or in ingress or in the service that updates the load balancer, I will try again in a new cluster and update the question.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak I was able to make this work, first I need to get the load balancer id executing ` k describe svc ingress-nginx-controller --namespace=ingress-nginx` and then pasting in the annotation `kubernetes.digitalocean.com/load-balancer-id: “xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx”` thanks for your comments, it helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [agusgambina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2853555/agusgambina) has mentioned in the comment, problem is solved:

> I was able to make this work, first I need to get the load balancer id executing  `k describe svc ingress-nginx-controller --namespace=ingress-nginx` and then pasting in the annotation `kubernetes.digitalocean.com/load-balancer-id: “xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx”` thanks for your comments, it helped me to solve the issue.

This problem described also [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/issue-with-waiting-for-http-01-challenge-propagation-failed-to-perform-self-check-get-request-from-acme-challenges) and there is also a tutorial
[How to Set Up an Nginx Ingress with Cert-Manager on DigitalOcean Kubernetes](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes#step-2-%E2%80%94-setting-up-the-kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller).